# When a question is deleted, it should be deleted from all sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, deleted-questions

[How do you locally redirect DNS requests in a *NIX environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391743/how-do-you-locally-redirect-dns-requests-in-a-nix-environment) was moved to Serverfault at [[1]](https://serverfault.com/questions/63266/how-do-you-locally-redirect-dns-requests-in-a-nix-environment), but that link is a 404, assumably because the question was deleted on Serverfault. Dead links are not good UI, and will annoy anyone who stumbles upon the question from, e.g., Google.

I suggest that when a question is deleted, it should be deleted from all the Stackoverflow-affiliated sites that it happened to be on. IOW, delete the pointer, too.

Comment: You could flag for Moderator attention, in the interim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, something else happened. The question was double-posted by the owner (so migrated, and THEN manually reposted). A SF moderator then merged the two together, functionally destroying the migrated Q.

[How do you locally redirect DNS requests in a *NIX environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/63188/how-do-you-locally-redirect-dns-requests-in-a-nix-environment)

edit: we now do 301 redirects for migrated posts that have been deleted.

Comment: Does that mean the functionality the OP describes already exists (i.e. deleting a migrated question removes it from both sites)?

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable, as the data indicating migration exists on both sides.  The links are there so each site knows where the question lives in the other site's DB.

You'd just need to have an event that fires when a post which has been migrated gets deleted.  It'd be a sort of reverse-migration, except rather than copying the question, it deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue with [Machine not taking keyboard input](https://serverfault.com/questions/81745/machine-not-taking-keyboard-input-closed) .  It got migrated to SU, I decided it wasn't a worthwhile question and deleted it.  But the question is still on SF.