# Delete question from all sites

Tags: support, migration, deleted-questions

i posted [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/81745/machine-not-taking-keyboard-input-closed) a while back on SF, it was (rightly) moved to SU.  After a while, I decided the question was worthless.  I couldn't delete it on SF, so I went to SU and deleted it, expecting the closed question on SF to dissappear as well.  It didn't, and I can't seem to delete it or flag it for moderator attention.

A similar question was asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/when-a-question-is-deleted-it-should-be-deleted-from-all-sites) but the answer doesn't address my situation.

Comment: I was able to flag the question yesterday and get it deleted, so it looks like all is well on this front now.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Hit the flag -> requires moderator attention button on the two sites and request it. In fact, it has already gone from SU, so just SF to go.</s>

OK, OK I get it. Sorry for being slow today.

I guess "flag another of your own posts explaining the situation and citing the affected post" is the best option, then - closely followed by "post on meta". Sorry for being a muppet there.

Comment: You can't flag the post, there's no link - that's the point. It has been mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to the `team @ stackoverflow.com` explaining the situation.

Make sure to provide links to anything that might be useful for making a decision.

---

If we had the [Ability to flag locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/ability-to-flag-locked-posts), then I would suggest that you do that instead.

<sup>The ability to flag your own posts was originally disallowed. So I think this will happen eventually.</sup>

Comment: -1: No need to send an email for something like that. That's what the moderator flag is for.

Comment: @balpha - there's no "flag" link on migrated posts so the OP's only choice is to e-mail or post here.

Comment: @ChrisF: There's a feature request open to change this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/ability-to-flag-locked-posts Also, it's always possible to flag any question and just refer to the one you're flagging about. That's not an optimal solution (the requested change would be), but it's better to tell people this workaround instead of making them use the team email address, which would mean more work for all sides.

Comment: @balpha - Cheers, I couldn't find that to reference.

Comment: @balpha This answer originally did mention flagging for moderator attention, but then I realized that was impossible.

Comment: @balpha, I added that link to the answer. Thank you.